# Select all rows where two columns have the same value?

Tags: sql, database

I'm working with SQL and was wondering how I would get all of the rows where values in 2 columns are equal. For example, imagine this table:

```
+----+---------+
| ID | Version |
+----+---------+
| AB |       1 |
| AB |       1 |
| BA |       2 |
| BA |       2 |
| CB |       1 |
+----+---------+
```

I want to select all rows where the IDs and versions match other rows with the same values in their ID and Version columns. In other words, I want to find duplicate values. So the desired output would be:

```
+----+---------+
| ID | Version |
+----+---------+
| AB |       1 |
| AB |       1 |
| BA |       2 |
| BA |       2 |
+----+---------+
```

How would I go about doing this as efficiently as possible in a table with over a million rows?

Comment: Why would you want duplicated rows in your output though?

Comment: Match to what? From the question I expect you need all rows with  `ID = Version`, but your output violates this. You should be more precise, it is not clear why <'CB', 1> does not "match" (to itself, for example). Do you want to find all the duplicates?

Comment: @astentx I have clarified my question, does that make it clearer? Edit: Yes, I want to find all of the duplicates.

Comment: @Californium So it is clear. But please add more info about user_id, because may be it is better and more performant to answer the target question instead of partial result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method are probably window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id, version) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

If you have an index on `(id, version)` (or `(version, id)`), then the database engine should be able to take advantage of that.

Comment: Does ```t``` in this case stand for the table name?

Comment: `from t` is a table name. `) t` is a (derived table) table alias.

Comment: @Californium . . . Yes.  You didn't specify the table name in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a duplicates count per group, then use `GROUP BY ... HAVING`. If you need an overall count of duplicated rows, then use another aggregation over the group by.

For Oracle ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2fef213db05922a46d2da7b7f6ee2bc1)) it can be done in single step:

```
with a as (
  select 1 as id, 'A' as v from dual union all
  select 1 as id, 'A' as v from dual union all
  select 1 as id, 'B' as v from dual union all
  select 1 as id, 'B' as v from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'C' as v from dual
)
select  sum(count(1)) as total_duplicates
  , count(count(1)) as duplicate_groups
from a
group by id, v
having count(1) > 1
```

For SQL Server ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=357559353257ea1dfa1a21ce68b10e00)), for example, it does not work, so I've added another select over it

```
with a as (
  select 1 as id, 'A' as v  union all
  select 1 as id, 'A' as v  union all
  select 1 as id, 'B' as v  union all
  select 1 as id, 'B' as v  union all
  select 2 as id, 'C' as v 
)
select sum(cnt) as total_duplicates
  , count(cnt) as duplicate_groups
from (
  select count(1) as cnt
  from a
  group by id, v
  having count(1) > 1
) as q
```

```
| total_duplicates | duplicate_groups |
+-------------------------------------+
| 4                | 2                |
```